# Cant make two buttons use the same function in jquery with html

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code to add some content to a div when a button is clicked and in that code it adds a button called `"teamReq_"+index+"_AddYear"` (index is a number taken from a hidden input field).

So spamming the button will create divs:   `teamReq_1_AddYear`,`teamReq_2_AddYear`,`teamReq_3_AddYear` etc

at the end of the function I run the following code:

```
 document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_AddYear").onclick = addYear;
```

`addYear` is a function defined later in the js file, however it only runs for the latest button created e.g. if I created 3 buttons it would only run for `teamReq_3_AddYear`, the other two would cause the web page to reload. How do I fix this?
Full code for generating the div's:

```
    document.getElementById("addTeam").onclick = addTeam;  function addTeam() {
event.preventDefault();
var index = document.getElementById("varTeamsReq").value;
var existingHTML = document.getElementById("teamsReqTab").innerHTML;
existingHTML += "<div style=\"overflow:hidden; width:1000px\" id=\"teamReq_"+index+"\">";
existingHTML += "  <div style=\"float:left\">";
existingHTML += "    <input id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Quantity\" type=\"number\" value=\"1\" min=\"1\" style=\"width:60px\">";
existingHTML += "  </div>";
existingHTML += "  <div style=\"float:left\" id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_MidText\">";
existingHTML += "    &nbsp;students from year&nbsp;"
existingHTML += "  </div>";
existingHTML += "  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"varTeamsReq_"+index+"_Years\" value=\"2\" id=\"varTeamsReq_"+index+"_Years\"/>";
existingHTML += "  <div style=\"float:left; overflow:hidden;\" id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Years\">";
existingHTML += "    <div style=\"float:left\" id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Year_1_Div\">";
existingHTML += "      <input id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Year_1\" type=\"number\" value=\"7\" min=\"7\" max=\"13\" style=\"width:60px\">";
existingHTML += "    </div>";
existingHTML += "  </div>";
existingHTML += "  <div style=\"float:left\" id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_AddYear_Div\">";
existingHTML += "    <button id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_AddYear\"><i class=\"fa fa-plus fa-1x\" style=\"transform: scale(1.3); color:#00FF00\"></i></button>";
existingHTML += "  </div>";
existingHTML += "  <div style=\"float:left\" id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_DelYear_Div\">";
existingHTML += "  </div>";
existingHTML += "  <div style=\"float:right\">";
existingHTML += "    <button id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Remove\"><i class=\"fa fa-minus fa-1x\" style=\"transform: scale(1.3); color:#FF0000\"></i></button>";
existingHTML += "  </div>";
existingHTML += "</div>";
document.getElementById("teamsReqTab").innerHTML = existingHTML;
document.getElementById("varTeamsReq").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("varTeamsReq").value) + 1;
document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_AddYear").onclick = addYear;
document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_Remove").onclick = delTeam;
```

}

Full code for the addYear function:

```
function addYear() {
event.preventDefault();
var index = this.id.substring(8,this.id.length-8);
var year = document.getElementById("varTeamsReq_"+index+"_Years").value;
if (year == 7) {
  document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_AddYear_Div").innerHTML = "";
}
if (year == 2) {
  document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_DelYear_Div").innerHTML = "<button id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_DelYear\"><i class=\"fa fa-minus fa-1x\" style=\"transform: scale(1.3); color:#FF0000\"></i></button>";
  document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_DelYear").onclick = delYear;
}
for (i = 2; i < year; i++) {
  document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_Year_"+i+"_Div").innerHTML = "&nbsp;,&nbsp;<input id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Year_"+i+"\" type=\"number\" value=\"7\" min=\"7\" max=\"13\" style=\"width:60px\"/>";
}
var existingHTML = document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_Years").innerHTML;
existingHTML += "    <div style=\"float:left\" id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Year_"+year+"_Div\">";
existingHTML += "      &nbsp;or&nbsp;";
existingHTML += "      <input id=\"teamReq_"+index+"_Year_"+year+"\" type=\"number\" value=\"7\" min=\"7\" max=\"13\" style=\"width:60px\"/>";
existingHTML += "    </div>";
document.getElementById("teamReq_"+index+"_Years").innerHTML = existingHTML;
document.getElementById("varTeamsReq_"+index+"_Years").value = parseInt(document.getElementById("varTeamsReq_"+index+"_Years").value) + 1;
```

}

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: Maybe post your full code, so that we can see what's happening.

Comment: @11684 I am using jQuery so if the solution requires jQuery then that's fine.

Comment: @AkshayArora updated to incude all faulty code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is getting the existing html, adding new html and adding the result back into the div. By doing this you are removing all click events of the existing html.

Every time you click the "add team" button you copy and paste the current html, add new html (new row) but only add the onclick event for the new row.

Instead you could append the new html like this:

```
var holder = document.getElementById('teamsReqTab');
holder.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newHTML)
```

I have made a fiddle with this code implemented http://jsfiddle.net/od828m98/

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Do you know why that happens though? does .onclick = function just change the html to include onclick="function()"?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a native speaker. I'll try to explain:You are replacing the html within #teamsReqTab each time you add a new team. When doing this there are no longer any click events attached to #teamsReqTab. However you do create a new click event for the new row, that's why the latest row always works, but the rest stops working.